# Creating pytest plugins

Tags: python, plugins, pytest, setup.py

I use pytest for unit testing my code. In regards to that, I was trying to create a pytest plugin that could be used throughout my directory. I could either create a conftest.py file in the main root directory or create an installable pytest plugin. I prefer the second option.

However, the pytest documentation does give a good guide on how to proceed with creating and installing a user defined plugin. I created the setup.py in the parent directory to the directory in which my conftest.py exists. My setup.py looked as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="tryplugin",
    packages = ['pluginTry'],
    version = "1.0.0",

    # the following makes a plugin available to pytest
    entry_points = {
        'pytest11': [
            'name_of_plugin = pluginTry',
        ]
    },
    classifiers=["Framework :: Pytest"],
)
```

Next I run the command:
`python3 setup.py install`

My plugin then appears on `pytest list`

However, the command line pytest option which my conftest.py creates does not appear in `pytest -h`. Nor does my fixtures come on `pytest --fixtures`

Rather, I get the following error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:718: in pyimport
    issame = self.samefile(modfile)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:204: in samefile
    return py.error.checked_call(
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py/_error.py:86: in checked_call
    raise cls("%s%r" % (func.__name__, args))
E   py.error.ENOTDIR: [Not a directory]: samefile('/Users/myName/Desktop/MainDirectory/pluginTry/conftest.py', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tryplugin-1.0.0-py3.8.egg/pluginTry/conftest.py')
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Nevermind! Resolved

Comment: Great! Please add an answer post below describing how the problem was fixed.